# In Hammerspoon init, is it necessary to assign event handlers to globals?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, global-variables, hammerspoon

I just started using Hammerspoon, and wrote some initialization code (at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/103f57dfeb0c9346ee817825659fbf5a). I was careful not to leak global variables, but a friend pointed me to a comment posted at https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/1103 that recommended doing so. It said "as a general rule of thumb, all watchers and timers should be captured in a global variable...". When that comment was posted in 2016, the current version of Lua (see https://www.lua.org/versions.html) was 5.3. That is still the case.

Is it true that assigning event handlers to global variables is helpful? Is there really a risk that my event handlers would be garbage collected? If so, is this a feature or a bug of the Hammerspoon runtime? (Feels like a bug to me.) If a feature, why is this reasonable?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you still need to do that, but if you do, it's a design flaw and/or bug in Hammerspoon, and should definitely be considered a hacky workaround rather than a good practice.

Comment: I have tested this by waiting until overnight (when the system had slept) and then unplugging the USB hub to see if any notifications were displayed. When the handler was saved in a global variable, the notifications were displayed, and when the handler was NOT saved in a global, the notifications were NOT displayed.